# How to get array item from json, React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

When I print `console.log(data.results);` it gives an array of object.

I need to get the original_title, so that would be `data.results[0].original_title`, but in the console it gives

> data.results undefined

In the end I want to get each original_item from the array of objects.

```
import './AutoCompleteText.css'

export default class AutoCompleteText extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){

        super(props)

        this.state = {
            inputText: '',
            movies: null

        };

    }

    onTextChange = (event) => {
        const value = event.target.value;
        this.setState(() => ({ inputText: value }));
        this.componentDidMount()

    }


    async componentDidMount(){
        const valuee = this.state.inputText;
        const api_key = 'fee1974c04959ee06151f1e6569934b6';
        const url = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=${api_key}&language=en-US&query=${valuee}`;

        const response = await fetch(url);
        const data = await response.json();
        this.setState({movies: data.results})
        console.log(data.results);

    }


    render () {
        const { inputText } = this.state;

        return (
            <div className="AutoCompleteText">
                <input value={inputText} onChange={this.onTextChange} type="text" />


            </div>
        )
    }
};
```

Comment: Instead of showing us code, can you show us json array getting in `data.results` and what you have tried to get original_title from each json object? hint: use `.map()`

Comment: Also if `data.results` is undefined, see what does `data` contain at the point of retrieval

Comment: Where are you doing `console.log(data.results);` in your code and seeing an array of objects in the console and where are you doing `data.results[0].original_title` and seeing `data.results is undefined`?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by using .map(), thank you Prasad Telkikar

```
this.state.movies.slice(0, 8).map(item => {
                            return <li id={item.id} onClick={this.onClickfunction.bind(this, item.title)} > {item.title} <p>{item.vote_average} Rating, {item.release_date.slice(0, 4)}</p>  </li>
```